# Strange Java serialization issue

Tags: java, serialization

I have a simple java abstract class:

```
abstract public class MyClass implements Streamable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5593048244217796061L;
...
protected MyClass() { }
...
abstract public ReturnType abstractMethod(ArgType crd);}
```

All types mentioned are also streamable (i'm not using default Java serialization, but some "GWT" serializer).

Now, i have A LOT of classes which work like this:

```
public abstract class AnotherClass implements Streamable {

protected AnotherClass() { }

protected void initDeterminators() {
    MyClass determinator = new MyClass(conditions) {            
        @Override
        public ReturnType abstractMethod(ArgType crd) {
            //some code
        }
    };
    addDeterminator(determinator);
}}
```

While serializing the "AnotherClass" i'm getting an error:

```
com.nkdata.gwt.streamer.client.StreamerException: Error creating streamer for class package.AnotherClass$1
```

Adding "Serial UIID" didn't help. "MyClass" do have protected default ctor. What should i do in order to make it serializable? Can i avoid changing all those other classes which make use of "MyClass"?

Comment: Your error message seems like error from GWT. Are you using google web toolkit in your app? If not, why do you want to use GWT for serialization?

Comment: Yes. I had problems with regular Java serialization (i don't want to write serialization code and Java serialization wasn't able to handle some complex-value hashmaps i have) and GWT seemed to work.

Comment: The exception seems to be complaining about the anonymous class you are using in the initDeterminators() method.  If you can't find a work around, I suggest promoting this anonymous class to a normal class and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: The anonymous class in your example above does not contain a default constructor.

Comment: @Palamino - but it's super class does... How should i declare the default constructor of anonymous class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out i had some cross references i didn't mentioned for sake of simplicity:
in place of

```
//some code
```

i was calling the method of outer "AnotherClass" instance and it seems that's a no-no for serialization.

I've solved by:

1) avoiding anonymous class

2) passing "conditions" and "this" to the constructor of that class.

3) instead of

```
>some code calling outer method<
```

i've did

```
>some code calling "parent.method()"<
```